# Is it possible to burn a MacOS application on a disk?

Tags: games, optical-drive

I have made a game in Xcode (Objective-C) and I now have a finished product. I know a few people that are willing to test the game. I thought it might be cool to give the game to them on a disk, like how you’d buy real games in a store. But I don’t know how, or if it’s even possible.

I have a MacBook Pro with built-in optical drive. My application is about 4GB.

Does anyone know if it’s possible to do this? And if it is, how would I do it and what do I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Your MacBook Pro's built-in optical drive is a "Super Drive" and capable of writing to at least CD-R and DVD-R disks.

Buy writable CDs and DVDs and insert them into your Mac. macOS's Finder includes the ability to write to these disks.

See [How to Burn Files to a DVD / CD on Mac OS](http://osxdaily.com/2018/07/11/how-burn-files-data-disc-mac/) for detailed instructions:

> 1. Create a new folder on the desktop (or elsewhere) and place the files you want to burn to the disc inside that folder
> 2. Select the folder you just created containing the files you wish to burn to the DVD / CD
> 3. With the folder selected, pull down the “File” menu and choose “Burn ‘Folder’ to Disc…”
> 4. You’ll be presented with a “Burn Disc” window, when you see this, insert the blank DVD or CD disc into the drive
> 5. Insert a blank disc to burn files to
> 6. Label the disc you want to burn accordingly, and optionally choose a burn speed, then click on “Burn” to start the process

[image]